# KSH script returns 249 as exit code

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, exit-code

A korn shell script is failing with a return code of 249. I am executing the script from a program in a proprietary language. Could anyone please let know what 249 exit code means . The OS is RHEL 6.

Comment: Process exit codes are not standardized (except for zero meaning "success" and everything other than zero meaning "failure"). What `249` means depends on the script (or on the commands executed by the script).

Comment: Point accepted , the thing is 249 is not standardized. The script is trying to append data to a file written in some other user's folder. The file it is trying to append data to has open read/write permissions for all users. So , i do not think that this is an access violation error. Any leads from people who have had faced this 249 error would be helpful.

Comment: KSH scripts return the exit code for the last instruction they executed. Execute the script with -x flag for ksh and you will see were the script is finishing and returning that value: ```ksh -x SCRIPT```

Comment: After installing gcc in my linux system I went to /usr/include and did `grep 249 * */* */*/*`. A lot of possible errors turn up. The only possible clue is 
`asm-parisc/errno.h:#define      ELOOP           249     /* Too many symbolic links encountered */`. Did you use symbolic links (redirecting to each other)?

Comment: yes there are symbolic links in the script. There is a heavy usage of environment variables to retreive folder and file names. I am not an expert on this subject and also learning like many of us.

Answer (score 0):

The exit code returned by wait is the lowest 8 bits of whatever value the process returned.

So, the return code could have been either `249 or -7 (signed -> unsigned conversion).`

You need to consult documentation for the language - it may actually return negative numbers, like some old COBOL implementations used to do.  And, as noted, without using the error return code documentation for the language in question - there is absolutely no way to know what the return code means othere than an error condition existed.  IF you post the name of the 'proprietary language' someone may have an adhoc answer for you.

You need the documentation, really.